# Upgrading makie package

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I have Julia 1.5.2 in my machine. Recently I installed a plotting package called `Makie` and its backend `GLMakie` in a Julia environment. The package was initially working fine. But then after adding a few other packages `MakieThemes`, `AbstractPlotting`, `AlgebraOfGraphics`, and running the same code, is giving me an error (`ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access Scene at index [3]`).

A post on the net suggested that one of the packages might have downgraded `GLMakie` package. Now even after removing and reinstalling `GLMakie` package is still giving the same error. I have tried updating the package `Pkg.update("GLMakie")` but the package doesn't seem to get upgraded (`0.1.13`). On github there seems to be version `0.1.29`

Does anyone know why it isn't getting upgraded.

Also for information here is the code.

```
using Makie
using GLMakie
using RDatasets
using DataFrames

#Data
df = dataset("datasets", "iris")

#Scatterplot
fig, axis, scatterObj = scatter(
    df.SepalLength,
    df.SepalWidth;
    markersize = 9,
    color = :lightblue
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue. It was caused by `StatsMakie` which is now deprecated.
Solved by removing StatsMakie (`]rm StatsMakie`) which allowed the other 2 packages to get updated to their latest releases. Update Makie by `Pkg.update(PackageSpec(name="Makie",version="0.12.0"))` and similarly for GLMarkie.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you got things updated.  The error you had was for a different reason though. Your figure is just the scatterplot here, so the Scene `scatter(...)` returns has just the axis and the scatter figure, so two not three elements. ie:

```
#Scatterplot
axis, scatterObj = scatter(
    df.SepalLength,
    df.SepalWidth;
    markersize = 9,
    color = :lightblue
)
```